# Use of ui-select with Angularjs and ajax values

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, select, ui-select

I'm trying to switch from Select2 v4 to [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) angularjs wrapper.
I fill value through ajax call:

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'roles'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.roles = response.data.result;
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
```

and I would like to show with select2 theme the role name and save into my form variable role id. With Select2 I used this code:

```
<select class="form-control select2"
    style="width: 100%;" name="role" data-ng-model="newUser.role"
    data-ng-options="role.idRole as role.role for role in roles track by role.role"
    required>
</select>
```

but it doesn't with placeholder, default value and allow-clear. So I set with ui-select:

```
<ui-select style="width: 100%;" theme="select2" data-ng-model="newUser.role"> 
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select role"> <span data-ng-bind="role.role"></span> </ui-select-match> <ui-select-choices
        repeat="role in (roles | filter: $select.search) track by role.role">
    <span data-ng-bind="role.role"></span> </ui-select-choices> 
</ui-select>
```

but it doesn't work, I see only empty select with no element found. But it is odd that with bootstrap theme I see the value also if I can't see witch I select.
Could you help me?

***UPDATE***
with select2 v3.4.5 (I'm using 4) it has the same problems as bootstrap theme.

Comment: Are there any console errors?

Comment: No, there aren't errors. If I use role.idRole as role.role for like select2 I receive error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switch to bootstrap and I used this code:

```
<ui-select theme="bootstrap" style="width: 100%;"
    data-ng-model="newUser.role" required> 
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select role">
       {{$select.selected.role}}
    </ui-select-match> 
    <ui-select-choices
       repeat="role.idRole as role in (roles | filter: $select.search) track by role.role">
       <span data-ng-bind="role.role"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

where I could add `allow-clear = true` inside `ui-select-match`